# parsing an xml file in tFileInputXML

Tags: xml-parsing, talend

How can I parse this xml file in tfileinputxml component in Talend. Basically, I am interested in output like:

```
tablespace|dw|john
tablespace|site|john
user|site|john
user|dw|john
```

Here is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<objects>
    <tablespaces>
        <tablespace>
            <dbname>dw</dbname>
            <user>john</user>
        </tablespace>
        <tablespace>
            <dbname>site</dbname>
            <user>john</user>
        </tablespace>
    </tablespaces>
    <users>
        <username>
            <dbname>site</dbname>
            <user>john</user>
        </username>
        <username>
            <dbname>dw</dbname>
            <user>john</user>
        </username>
    </users>
</objects>
```

Answer (score 0):

After a discussion with client, it was decided to change the structure of the file.